# Compute the extreme points of a polyhedron $P$ and write $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ as a linear combination of these.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Compute the extreme points of a polyhedron $P$ and write $(1/2,1/2,1/2)$ as a linear combination of these.

I want to compute all the extreme points of the set $P$ (polyhedron) in $\mathbb R^3$ satisfying the inequalities:

$-x -y-z \le -1$

$-x + y + z \le 1$

$x -y +z \le 1$

$x + y -z \le 1$

$x + y+ z \le 2$

I've computed  $\text{ext}(P) = \{e_1,e_2,e_3,(1/2,1/2,1),(1/2,1,1/2),(1,1/2,1/2)\}$ and $\text{rec}(P)={0}$, so $P = \text{ext}(P)$.

However, $(1/2,1/2,1/2) \in P$, cannot be written as a convex combination of the vectors in $\text{ext}(P)$.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The point $(\frac 12,\frac 12,\frac 12)$ *can* be written as a convex combination of three of the points you gave. In particular,

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac 12,\frac 12,\frac 12\right)
  & = \frac 12 \left( \frac 12,\frac 12,1 \right) \\
  & + \frac 14 (1,0,0)\\
  & + \frac 14 (0,1,0)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oww, can't see why I didn't saw that. Can you confirm that my computations of the recession cone and extreme points are correct ? Thanks !